# Does anyone know such a function?

Tags: logic

Let's consider for instance 4 limit values L1 < L2 < L3 < L4.

For now, I need a multivariate function of 2 variables `x1` and `x2` defined on `[L1,L4]^2` so that:

```
- if L3≤x1 or L3≤x2, then L3≤f(x1,x2)≤L4       
- else if L2≤x1 or L2≤x2 then, L2≤f(x1,x2)≤L3    
- otherwise (x1<L2 and x2<L2), L1≤f(x1,x2)≤L2
```

Here is a logical tree to help : [logical tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZDhU.png)

Also I would like that for instance if L2<x1 and L2<x2 then f(x1,x2) is closer of L3 than if L2< x1 and L2>x2.

One solution is to define a linear function with conditional values for E_min, Emax, mean_min, mean_max.

> f(x1,x2)=E_min +
> (mean(x1,x2)-mean_min)/(mean_max-mean_min)*(E_max-E_min)

For instance, for L1=0, L2=33, L3=66, L4=100, constant value are given in this picture [constants example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIcTE.png).

Does anyon has another function idea? (Maybe that wouldn't need the definition of conditional constant values?

This question is related to my previous post:
[How to combine two risk functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4556414/how-to-combine-two-risk-functions)

Thank you for reading

Comment: yes I meant if at least one of (x1,x2) is higher than L3, then L3<f(x1,x2)<L4 and so on. I can make a logical tree illustration if it helps

Comment: I have added it to the initial post

Comment: you are right, there is a mistake, thank you ! I meant : "x1<L2 and x2<L2 "

Comment: How about something like $f(x_1,x_2) = \max(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: @DougM yes that is what I am using also for now. However, I would like a more progressive function: I would need that if $x1_A<x1_B$, then $f(x1_A,x2)<f(x1_B,x2)$

Comment: @AnneBauval I corrected and put it into parenthesis